# grep a variable within an if statement

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, variable

Maybe I am approaching this the wrong way, so I am open for suggestions.  I am trying to avoid adding the output of INSTALLED_LIST to a file.  I wish to use it within a variable.

Basically, I want to check if a list (INSTALLATION_PACKAGES) of packages are installed on a system.  If not, record which ones failed to install, record the information, and exit.  Outside of the if statement, this works fine (see commented out line), I am just having issues implementing it within an if statement.

Thx in advance for your help.

```
INSTALLED_LIST=`dpkg --list`

for i in $INSTALLTION_PACKAGES; do
  apt-get -y install $i
  # echo "$INSTALLED_LIST" | grep -ie "^ii  $i "
  if ! echo "$INSTALLED_LIST" | grep -ie "^ii  $i "  ; then
    echo $i >> $FAILED_INSTALL
  fi
done
```

Comment: You are approaching it the wrong way - `INSTALLED_LIST`'s content isn't going to magically update itself after you did `apt-get install`.  You should test either `apt-get`'s exit status, or run `dpkg -l $i | grep ...` for each package.

Comment: Thank you...   I decided to check the exit status of apt-get install.

Answer (score 2):

If you want all packages in `$INSTALLATION_PACKAGES` to be installed, just `apt-get install` all of them and *then* check whether any of them failed:

```
apt-get -y $INSTALLATION_PACKAGES
list=$(dpkg -l | grep ^ii)
for i in $INSTALLATION_PACKAGES do
    echo "$list" | grep -w "$i" || echo "$i" >> $FAILED_INSTALL
done
```